# joining counts in sql

Tags: sql, join, union

I'm pretty new to SQL, and am trying to do something not the dumb way. To give some context, I'm comparing the planning and realized uses of vehicles in a carrier branch, and need to count the occurrences of both. I have a `with subquery as` that returns something like the following

```
PLANNED  | REALIZED
---------+----------
TRUCK    | BI-TREM
TRUCK    | TRUCK
TRUCK    | TRUCK
TRUCK    | TRUCK
TRUCK    | TRUCK
CARRETA  | CARRETA
CARRETA  | CARRETA
TRUCK    | KOMBI
TRUCK    | BI-TREM
CARRETA  | KOMBI
CARRETA  | KOMBI
TRUCK    | TRUCK
CARRETA  | CARRETA
CARRETA  | BI-TREM
CARRETA  | CARRETA
CARRETA  | CARRETA
TRUCK    | BI-TREM
```

And would like to return something like the following

```
VEHICLE | TOTAL_PLANNED | TOTAL_REALIZED
--------+---------------+---------------
CARRETA | 8             | 5
TRUCK   | 9             | 5
BI-TREM | 0             | 4
KOMBI   | 0             | 3
```

I've tried the following

```
select PLANNED, 
       count(*) as TOTAL_PLANNED
       null as REALIZED,
       0 as TOTAL_REALIZED
from subquery
group by PLANNED

union all

select null as PLANNED,
       0 as TOTAL_PLANNED,
       REALIZED,
       count(*) as TOTAL_REALIZED
from subquery
group by REALIZED
```

which returns

```
CARRETA 8   NULL    0
TRUCK   9   NULL    0
NULL    0   BI-TREM 4
NULL    0   CARRETA 5
NULL    0   TRUCK   5
NULL    0   KOMBI   3
```

I've also tried all available joins using the subquery, to no success. In fact, `RIGHT JOIN` works, but only because all planned vehicles are also in the realized side: if some didn't, I would have a NULL at the `VEHICLE` column.

Thanks for any help, even if just a pointer to a SQL command.

PS.: this query have to work on both SQL Server and Oracle, so I'm striving for pure SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT PLANNED_REALIZED AS VEHICLE, 
       SUM(TOTAL_PLANNED) AS TOTAL_PLANNED,
       SUM(TOTAL_REALIZED) AS TOTAL_REALIZED
FROM
(select PLANNED AS PLANNED_REALIZED, 
        1 as TOTAL_PLANNED
        0 as TOTAL_REALIZED
 from subquery
 union all
 select REALIZED as PLANNED_REALIZED,
        0 as TOTAL_PLANNED,
        1 as TOTAL_REALIZED
 from subquery
) SQ
GROUP BY PLANNED_REALIZED
```

Comment: That works! It's seems a bit convoluted, and I chose as the answer just because more people liked it. It'll take some time to understand both answers...

Comment: It may *look* more convoluted, but it only requires two reads of the table, as opposed to 2 x (n+1) reads required for Simon's solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
select T.VEHICLE, 
       (SELECT count(*) FROM Table AS T1 WHERE T1.PLANNED = T.VEHICLE) AS TOTAL_PLANNED
       (SELECT count(*) FROM Table AS T2 WHERE T2.REALIZED = T.VEHICLE) AS TOTAL_REALIZED,
from (SELECT DISTINCT PLANNED AS VEHICLE FROM Table
        UNION SELECT DISTINCT REALIZED AS VEHICLE FROM Table) AS T
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, too! Though, I'll have to go to some length to find out how, without using `group by` :)